# If you have --optimization on with syncfusion "17.4.51", I get a weird build issue

Tags: angular, syncfusion, angular9

I have a problem using Syncfusion "17.4.51" with an angular project I upgraded to angular 9. If I build with optimization set to true I get the following weird error:

```
ng serve -c=dev
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.
It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************

chunk {} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 1.49 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.js, main.js.map (main) 452 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 168 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 3.61 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {4} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 146 kB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-03-06T11:05:12.264Z - Hash: 7ef4d1671de0c1866c3f - Time: 13120ms

ERROR in Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Here's an extract from my angular.json

```
"qa": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
            }
          ]
        },
```

It works if I turn optimization off, but I'm not sure if that is what I want since it used to build fine with angular 8. I had thought initially that it was because I had ahead of time compilation on, but that seems to not be the case.

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing, or does syncfusion just not work with optimization?

Here is my package.json too:

```
{
  "name": "angular-template",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.2.4",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-base": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-buttons": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-grids": "^17.4.51",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-pivotview": "17.4.51",
    "@types/file-saver": "2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "google-maps": "^4.2.3",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mdn-polyfills": "^5.19.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.6",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "raven-js": "^3.27.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Also please let me know if I should provide any additional information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that we had hacks in our HTML/CSS that were for IE specifically and when we removed them the issue went away.

Sadly I can't say exactly why this caused an issue, but in the interest of finding some resolution here is an example of such a hack:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
 .text-icon > :nth-child(1n) {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
<![endif]-->
```

We removed these throughout our codebase and the issue went away.

This doesn't seem to be a Syncfusion specific issue, but rather related to upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 9 as the issue was the same even without Syncfusion in the repo at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the target in your `tsconfig.json` should be `"target": "es2015"`.

Comment: If you'd like, you can leave a comment on the question asking what the OP's target is.

Comment: I do have `"target": "es2015"`, but I'm guessing if this is the case then I should probably try to turn of differential loading, Will see if that changes anything.

Comment: Doesn't seem like that made any difference, so I'm still confused by where exactly this error is coming from.

Comment: I have a similar set up except that my version of @syncfusion/ej2-angular-base is 17.4.52, I don't use the pivotview, and I separate the vendor chunk.  I updated the base lib because of a comment on the following thread https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/149934/compatibility-with-angular-9

Answer (score 0):

validated your reported issue and unable to reproduce it by setting optimization to true (optimization is true by default). Prepared the angular sample in Angular 8 and then we updated the angular version to the latest (9.0.6) using “ng update @angular/cli @angular/core –allow-dirty –force” command.

[angular latest version update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfUVn.jpg)

Not faced any kind of issue as you mentioned while serving the sample. Attached the sample [here.](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/269092/ze/angular-old-optimization51607335)

[serving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K73ip.jpg)